# CLion - Way to go to C/C++ standard library implementation

Tags: c++, c, clion

In Java project with IntelliJ IDEA, I can go to the definition of any declared functions by `Ctrl+click`. But in CLion, I can see only header files.

Is there any way to connect `glibc` to CLion so I can see the implementation of the functions? I'm using gcc and g++ compiler.

Comment: C++ is not *that* automated like Java. You have to setup the includes/libraries etc manually.

Comment: It is not typical for standard library source code to be present on your system.  Also, there is a much greater diversity of C standard library implementations than there are of Java standard library implementations, and although glibc's source is available, most implementations' is not.  Program to the interface, not to a particular implementation.

Comment: And if you could do that with glibc, you'd probably wind up qualified to be a glibc maintainer.  Given the wide variety of platforms glibc supports, finding the actual implementation of a library call for your specific architecture can be challenging, and automating that even more so.  And that's just the C run-time library...

Comment: It is difficult to jump the standard library implication, but you can download the standard library implication if you want to look for some code.

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/